# Get specific links with target in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML source with Python using BeautifulSoup. What I need to get is to get the `href` of specific links (`<a>` tags). The feature I see is that those links all include `target='testwindow'` inside their tags, so maybe I look for that. How can I get those links?

This is my test sample. I would need to get **only** `http://example.com:20213/testweb1.2/testapp?WSDL`.

```
<td id="link3"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" style="height:1px;" width="0" border="0"><a href="http://example.com:20213/testweb1.2/testapp?WSDL">?HELLO</a></td>
<td id="link4"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" style="height:1px;" width="0" border="0"><a href="http://example.com:20213/testweb1.2/testapp?WSDL" target="testwindow">?WSDL</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BeautifulSoup.find`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
content = '<td id="link4"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" style="height:1px;" width="0" border="0"><a href="http://example.com:20213/testweb1.2/testapp?WSDL" target="testwindow">?WSDL</a></td>'
d = soup(content, 'html.parser').find('a', {'target':'testwindow'})['href']
```

Output:

```
'http://example.com:20213/testweb1.2/testapp?WSDL'
```

Comment: No, this will give me all links. I need only those having `target='testwindow'`

Comment: Great. What if we have more of these tags? Maybe use `find_all`? Can you edit your answer?